# How to check if elements in one array exist in another array if so print the count using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays

```
A=[1,2,3,4,6,5,5,5,8,9,7,7,7]
B=[1,5,7]
```

If elements of B in A then print the number of occurrences
output
1:1
5:3
7:3

Comment: while posting question, you must provide your attempt, so we can point you in right direction

Answer (score 2):

pythonic way:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a= [1,2,3,4,6,5,5,5,8,9,7,7,7]
>>> b = [1,5,7]
>>> counter = collections.Counter(a)
>>> {x:counter[x] for x in b}
{1: 1, 5: 3, 7: 3}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For sorted array you can come up with better algorithms that work faster, but generally easy and more native way without using libraries would be

```
for i in B:
    ans = 0
    for j in A:
        if i == j:
            ans += 1
    print(i,':',ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

both of the above answers worked.

I used  counter as B had all elements of A

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(A)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `pandas` so here is a simple solution:
Count everything, then return only the subset that overlap with the items in `B`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(A).value_counts().reindex(B).to_dict()
#{1: 1, 5: 3, 7: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package has a vectorized solution to this problem (disclaimer: i am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
keys, counts = npi.count(A)
counts = counts[npi.indices(keys, B)]
```